# Mysql multiple SELECT and Count query

Tags: mysql, select, count

Can you advice in whats the best way to combine multiple select and count into the one query

For example here are some queries that are from a test_table and work perfect on their own

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS 'Overall' FROM test_test WHERE country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' GROUP BY `city_name`;  

SELECT name, count(*) AS 'unallocated' FROM test_tab le WHERE country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' AND removed != '1' AND destination-value = '1234' GROUP BY `city_name`;
```

There's a few more queries i'll be running but I think if I get two working together ill be able to do the rest

I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' GROUP BY `city_name') AS "Overall", (SELECT count(*) AS 'unallocated' FROM test_table WHERE country_prefix = '44' AND city_code = '203' AND removed != '1' AND destination-value = '1234' GROUP BY 'city_name')
```

But unfortunately doesn't work

Would the best way to do this be using sum case when, something like this:

```
sum(case when destination-value = '1234' then 1 else 0 end) AS unallocated
```

Comment: any idea folks?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT city_name, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' THEN 1 END) AS Overall, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' AND removed != '1' AND destination-value = '1234' THEN 1 END) AS unallocated
FROM tablename
GROUP BY city_name;
```

or since the 2 cases contain common conditions, these conditions can be moved to a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT city_name, 
  COUNT(*) AS Overall, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN removed != '1' AND destination-value = '1234' THEN 1 END) AS unallocated
FROM tablename
WHERE country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203'
GROUP BY city_name;
```

In Mysql it's possible to simplify the code with the function `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT city_name, 
  COUNT(*) AS Overall, 
  SUM(removed != '1' AND destination-value = '1234') AS unallocated
FROM tablename
WHERE country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203'
GROUP BY city_name;
```

Comment: Could you advice on a 4th count query, trying to add to this query but brings up error
SELECT city_name,
COUNT(CASE WHEN country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Overall,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN country_prefix = '44' AND area_code = '203' AND removed = '1' AND destination-value = '880000' THEN 1 END)
AS `unallocated `,
COUNT(CASE WHEN country_prefix = '353' AND area_code = '203' AND not-removed = '1' AND destination-value = '880000' THEN 1 END) AS `Added`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN destination-value = '880000' AND notes IS NULL) AS `seclusion` FROM test_table GROUP BY city_name;

Comment: I'm trying to say that the notes value when it's anything bring back results

Comment: If `destination-value` and `not-removed` are column names then enclose them inside backticks. If the error does persists post it here.

Comment: COUNT(CASE WHEN destination-value = '880000' AND notes IS NULL) AS seclusion FROM test_table GROUP BY city_name;

Comment: Also in the last COUNT you are missing THEN 1 END

Comment: Thanks alot Forpas, I totally forgot the THEN 1 END and it's looking better but it's not providing the results I want. What I hope would of happened with NULL is that it would provide results for anything in the NOTES column which normally is empty except in rare occasions

Comment: AND notes IS NULL is not a condition for anything.

Comment: Thanks Forpas, ya found that when it wasnt getting the results I wanted, any advice on how to get those results?

Comment: I don't know your actual data. This answer is about the question you posted. If you have a new requirement you should post a new question with sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.